# Does Zookeeper need to have its own server with HAMR?

Tags: installation, bigdata, apache-zookeeper

This is in regard to a big data analytics engine put out by http://hamrtech.com

Does Zookeeper have to be on its own server with HAMR?

Answer (score 0):

No it does not have to be part of the hamr cluster but every node within the cluster must have access to it.